# get string in between using Reqular Expression

Tags: php, regex

I have a string in php as

```
$str = "@113_Miscellaneous_0 = 0@,@104_documentFunction_0 = 1@";
```

How do i apply regular expression so i can extract the strings in between the @ char
so that the resulting result will be an array say

```
result[0] = "113_Miscellaneous_0 = 0";  
result[1] = "104_Miscellaneous_0 = 1";
```

@Fluffeh thanks for editing
@ Utkanos - tried something like this

```
$ptn = "@(.*)@";  
preg_match($ptn, $str, $matches);  
print_r($matches);  

output:
     Array
        (
            [0] => \"113_Miscellaneous_0 = 0\",\"104_documentFunction_0 = 1\"
            [1] => \"113_Miscellaneous_0 = 0\",\"104_documentFunction_0 = 1\"
        )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a non-greedy match,

```
preg_match_all("/@(.*?)@/", $str, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Comment: Would this not catch the `,` as a match?

Comment: No, it will not catch the comma. Only text between each `@`.
Here's an example without laziness: `preg_match_all ('#@([^@]+)#', $str, $matches);`

Comment: Oh sorry for the wrong update, I myself got confused with red-X comment.

Comment: because im trying the regex from this [site](http://www.pagecolumn.com/tool/pregtest.htm), but i cant seem to have my expected result

Comment: What result you expect? I am getting the exact strings you need.

Comment: @Shubham - my mistake, i need to change to preg_match_all, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You might go about it differently:

```
$str = str_replace("@", "", $str);
$result = explode(",", $str);
```

**EDIT**

Alright, give this a try than:

```
$ptn = "/@(,@)?/";
$str = "@113_Miscellaneous_0 = 0@,@104_documentFunction_0 = 1@";
preg_split($ptn, $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 113_Miscellaneous_0 = 0
    [1] => 104_documentFunction_0 = 1
)
```

Comment: And what if there are commas in the expressions to be captured? Better to explode on '@' and then filter out the commas, I think.

Comment: @dnagirl that wasnt a requirement in the question but in that case see edit